# How do I transfer text messages from iPhone 5 (running iOS 10.3) to a Galaxy S5 (running Android 6) for free?

Tags: sms, ios

I love Android and I'm trying to get my friend to transfer to an Android phone from their iPhone. I can use iCloud and other apps to transfer contacts and other things, but I can't figure out how ton transfer text messages to the Galaxy S5. These are the things I've tried and some reasons that they don't seem to work:

- Google Drive (requires iOS 11 & phone can't update to that version)
- iCloud (doesn't include text messages until iOS 11.4 & phone can't update to that version)
- DrFone (seems to just hang)
- ATT Transfer App (doesn't seem to work)
- iSMS2Droid (went down March 18th, 2019, and isn't available anymore in app stores. I was able to make a backup of the iPhone using iTunes, but I can't find any app/program that can convert the text message database to an Android one).

Thanks so much!

Comment: So the main question is not "How to transfer SMS" but "How do I extract the SMS data from my iPhone". Therefore the main "challenge" is located in iOS - this makes it mainly iPhone related but not Android related.

Comment: Actually, @Robert, you can extract the sms database with iTunes, but since iSMSDroid is no longer an option, I'm unsure of how to convert it to an Android SMS database - therefore, I would say it's mostly an Android related issue especially since it involves migrating TO an Android phone.

Comment: I think there is typo in iSMSDroid, the name is iSMS**2**droid right? Based on the package name `org.faked.isms2droid` there is an old version of this app available on [ApkPure.com](https://apkpure.com/de/isms2droid-iphone-sms-import/org.faked.isms2droid).

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you @Robert !